# soql query to get whole month,except its last week

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

I want to query for records of a month, except that month's last year.
my soql query is this

```
select id,name from opportunity where CreatedDate=THIS_MONTH And WEEK_IN_MONTH IN (1,2,3)
```

soql query to get the whole month, except its last week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yoou tagged it apex so can you cheat?

```
Date today = System.today();
Integer cutoff = Date.daysInMonth(today.year(), today.month()) - 7;

System.debug([SELECT Id
    FROM Opportunity
    WHERE CreatedDate=THIS_MONTH AND DAY_IN_MONTH(CreatedDate) < :cutoff]);
```